# An option for select all that gets all values from all other options

Tags: reactjs, typescript, semantic-ui-react

I'm currently using **semantic ui react** and I have a dropdown that contains options to filter data. But this option relies on mapping from an array. I want to have this option and another option for selecting all of them. How would I display both of these options?

This is my attempt of having both of these options

```
const projectOptions = this.props.projects.map(project => ([{
        text: project.name,
        value: project.id.toString(),
        key: project.id
    },
        {
            text: "Select all", value: "select all"
        }
    ]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea, you need to append your "Select all" option to the `projectOptions` array. It just needs to happen outside of your `map`. Here's one way:

```
const projectOptions = [
    ...this.props.projects.map(project => ({
        text: project.name,
        value: project.id.toString(),
        key: project.id
    })),
    { text: "Select all", value: "select all" }
];
```

Answer (score 2):

You are adding the Select All option for every option in projects. The following code declares an array, adds the Select All option, and then appends the mapped objects in `projects`.

```
const projectOptions = [
    {
        text: "Select all", value: "select all"
    },
    ...this.props.projects.map(project => ({
        text: project.name,
        value: project.id.toString(),
        key: project.id
    }))
]
```